# deleting the html element still shows row of no value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

i have a code written in jquery here that removes a row of data. the problem is when i delete that row, it still displays an empty row. how can i remove that empty row?

```
            $(document).on('click','.btn_remove', function(){
            a++;                
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");  
            var deletedItem = $('#total'+button_id+'').text();
            var getTotal = $('#samp').val();
            a = parseFloat((getTotal) - (deletedItem));
            $('#total_pay').text(a);
            $('#samp').val(a);
            $('#inc').val(i);
            $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();               
            }); 
            });
```

here is my code for generating the HTML value :

```
       $('#add').click(function(){
        i++;
        var item_name = $('#dummy').val();
        var price = $('#getRequest').val();
        var quantity = $('#sale_qty').val();
        var total = price * quantity;
        $('.dynamic_field').append(
            '<tr id="row'+i+'"><td class="total1">'+item_name+'</td><td class="total2">'+quantity+'</td><td id="total'+i+'" class="total" value="'+total+'">'+total+'</td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove" name="remove" id="'+i+'">X</button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="i_name'+i+'" id="name'+i+'"><input type="hidden" name="quan'+i+'" id="quan'+i+'"><input type="hidden" name="tot'+i+'" id="tot'+i+'"></td></tr>');
        $("#getRequest").val(" ");
        $('#product_category').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $('#prod_name').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        $('#sale_qty').val(" ");
        });
```

HTML:

```
                    <label>Registered Items:</label>
                    <table class="table dynamic_field">
                    <thead>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    </thead>   
                    <tbody>
                    <!--empty-->

                    </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <label>TOTAL:&nbsp;<span id="total_pay" name="total_payment">0</span></label>
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see any kind of an array.

Comment: the html code is now above. i edited it

Comment: But there is no arrays in your code. What exact you mean by "array"?

Comment: You are just modifiying the DOM by removing those table rows.

Comment: how can i remove it completely?

Comment: `$('#row'+button_id+'').remove();` should remove this completely. What happens after the delete button is pressed? is there an empty `<tr>` tag?

Comment: yes there is an empty <tr> i suppose

Comment: i tried to run those codes in my end, and it is working fine. There is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: Check this link https://jsfiddle.net/wa8f2e8a/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$('#row'+button_id+'').closest('tr').remove();
```

I hope it works

Comment: Is your delete button in every 'tr' and has class .btn_remove if yes then try $(this).closest('tr').remove();